# Dump single rows (with blobs) to single files

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, blob

I am creating MySQLDumps for the sake of versioning of a database. The problem currently is a table with blobs.

My first approach would be to dump single tables to single files. But next, I want on this specific table to dump each row to a single file.

How can I accomplish this using MySQLdump?

Answer (score 1):

There are three(3) things you need to do

1. Provide a list to tables that you want to dump row by row
2. Use --skip-extended-insert, which forces each `INSERT` to be one row
3. Use [--hex-blob](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob)

Here is such a script

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpass
MYSQL_CONN="-h127.0.0.1 -P3306 --protocol=tcp -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"

DB_TO_DUMP=mydb
TBLISTFILE=/tmp/tables_in_${DB_TO_DUMP}.txt

TABLES_TO_SPLIT_BY_ROW="tb1 tb2 tb3"

SQL="SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE table_schema='${DB_TO_DUMP}'"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" > ${TBLISTFILE}

TBLIST=""
for TB in `cat ${TBLISTFILE}` ; do TBLIST="${TBLIST} ${TB}" ; done

DT=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
for TB1 in `echo "${TBLIST}"`
do
    ROW_BY_ROW=0
    for TB2 in `echo "${TABLES_TO_SPLIT_BY_ROW}"`
    do
        if [ "${TB1}" == "${TB2}" ] ; then ROW_BY_ROW=1 ; fi
    done
    MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS=""
    if [ ${ROW_BY_ROW} -eq 1 ]
    then
        MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--hex-blob --skip-extended-insert"
    fi
    DUMPFILE=${TB1}_${DT}.sql
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DB_TO_DUMP} ${TB1} > ${DUMPFILE}
done
```

Just supply the name of the database in the `DB_TO_DUMP` along with the tables whose rows are to be one by one in the `TABLES_TO_SPLIT_BY_ROW` variable.

Please note how the dumpfile name has a datetime appended to the table name so you can do some versioning based on the datetime. You can change that to be versioned any way you wish.

You did ask that each row be in its own file. I will leave that up to you to script.

Comment: Okay, I am using this to split the file: `split -l1 -a10 -d ../belege.sql` now one small problem: I better should name the file by the primary key in the dump.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing to split the single-table dump into one file per row, named by ID:

```
awk -F',' '/^INSERT/{print > gensub(".*\\(","", "G", $15)".sql"}' ../big.sql
```

Where my table has around 15 fields. This takes the 15th column, separated by "," and replaces out the remaining SQL part (there are more elegant ways to do this, works only because I have numeric-only identifiers)

This is full script - I happen to have only one such table, so it misses the logic of the other answer

```
#!/bin/bash
DBNAME=example
BIGTABLE=big

mysqldump $DBNAME --single-transaction --quick --complete-insert --skip-extended-insert --ignore-table=$DBNAME.$BIG | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' > sql/master.sql

rm -rf sql/master.d
mkdir sql/master.d

mysqldump $DBNAME --hex-blob --single-transaction --quick --complete-insert --skip-extended-insert $BIG | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' > sql/master.d/$BIG.sql

cd sql/master.d/
mkdir $BIG.d
cd $BIG.d

awk -F',' '/^INSERT/{print > gensub(".*\\(","", "G", $15)".sql"}' ../$BIG.sql
rm ../$BIG.sql
```